# UIDatePicker showing wrong dates when i printed it

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, uidatepicker

I have created  a small project with UIDatePicker (Time mode) and connected it to the value changed method .Inside that method i put one NSLog with selected time .When i changed value of UIDatePicker jam getting wrong value printing in my console

For eg: 
When i selected 9:19 AM  my console printing 2015-04-27 03:49:10 +0000

Why it's showing different values?

My code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *picker;
- (IBAction)pic:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



   //Value changed method 
    - (IBAction)pic:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"%@",self.picker.date);
    }
    @end
```

Comment: It's not wrong. You picked a time in local time but the log shows the time in UTC time. They are the same when you take into account your timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to log

```
[self.picker.date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]
```

Log is not right because of timezone, NSDate will automatically adjust the time offset when displaying the date.

Comment: exactly...its working fine. so if i want only time in long format then i have to use nsdateformatter and then take the time and convert into long format right?

Comment: Yes,you can use NSDateFormatter

Comment: sorry for the delay..selected your answer and thank you